# how to use the same tween on multiple words using superscrollorama?

Tags: javascript, html, tween, gsap

Me being a total newbie again here- 
I am trying to use http://johnpolacek.github.com/superscrollorama/ and as you can imagine the idea of java script to me is very overwhelming especially this 'tween' thing.

anyway I'm trying to make a scrolling animating word splash page and I wanted to use the same tween twice, I tried looking at FAQs and whatnot but even they are too advanced to me to understand quite yet (gah!) i tried just entering 'fade-it' twice but that doesn't work. neither does adding another 'fade-it' script at the bottom. obviously i'm missing something here. anyone wanna help what i assume is probably an easy problem to fix? ;)

```
<div id="raychulllogo">
    <h2 id="fade-it">I'M <br> <img src="images/raychulllogoDARK.png" > </h2>
</div>

<h2 id="spin-it"></h2>
<p id="med">AND I </p>
<h2 id="smush-it">PHOTOGRAPH,</h2>
<h2 id="scale-it">DESIGN</h2>
<h2 id="fade-it"> &amp; FILM </h2>
```

and here's the JavaScript:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/greensock/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="_/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="js/jquery.superscrollorama.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var controller = $.superscrollorama();
        // individual element tween examples
        controller.addTween('#fade-it', TweenMax.from( $('#fade-it'), .5, {css:{opacity: 0}}));
        controller.addTween('#scale-it', TweenMax.fromTo( $('#scale-it'), .25, {css:{opacity:0, fontSize:'20px'}, immediateRender:true, ease:Quad.easeInOut}, {css:{opacity:1, fontSize:'240px'}, ease:Quad.easeInOut}));
        controller.addTween('#smush-it', TweenMax.fromTo( $('#smush-it'), .25, {css:{opacity:0, 'letter-spacing':'30px'}, immediateRender:true, ease:Quad.easeInOut}, {css:{opacity:1, 'letter-spacing':'-10px'}, ease:Quad.easeInOut}), 0, 100); // 100 px offset for better timing
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Just as a note, Superscrollorama doesn't do the tweens itself. It uses Greensock.

Comment: yes, i actually went to the greenstock site and all it's just all very super confusing and foreign language to me. Trying to learn by doing, maybe not the best idea? ha!

Comment: i believe i've found the answer in the FAQ http://www.greensock.com/get-started-js/#faq (#6) but i'm not exactly sure how to implement it. could anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

It may be as easy as switching to classes, instead of ids (you can't have multiple identical ids). So change to this:

```
  <div id="raychulllogo">
    <h2 class="fade-it">I'M <br> <img src="images/raychulllogoDARK.png" > </h2>
   </div>
    <h2 class="spin-it"></h2>
    <p class="med">AND I </p>
    <h2 class="smush-it">PHOTOGRAPH,</h2>
    <h2 class="scale-it">DESIGN</h2>
    <h2 class="fade-it"> &amp; FILM </h2>
</div>
```

and

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/greensock/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="_/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="js/jquery.superscrollorama.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var controller = $.superscrollorama();
        // individual element tween examples
        controller.addTween('.fade-it', TweenMax.from( $('.fade-it'), .5, {css:{opacity: 0}}));
        controller.addTween('.scale-it', TweenMax.fromTo( $('.scale-it'), .25, {css:{opacity:0, fontSize:'20px'}, immediateRender:true, ease:Quad.easeInOut}, {css:{opacity:1, fontSize:'240px'}, ease:Quad.easeInOut}));
        controller.addTween('.smush-it', TweenMax.fromTo( $('.smush-it'), .25, {css:{opacity:0, 'letter-spacing':'30px'}, immediateRender:true, ease:Quad.easeInOut}, {css:{opacity:1, 'letter-spacing':'-10px'}, ease:Quad.easeInOut}), 0, 100); // 100 px offset for better timing
    });
</script>
```

Just to be clear, `<h2 id="fade-it">` changes to `<h2 class="fade-it">` etc. and `$('#fade-it')` changes to `$('.fade-it')` etc.

Comment: just tried this. doesn't seem to change anything. the first lines animate but the last one still doesn't for some reason. :(

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the same thing and the .class thing didn't work but I found a way to make it work:
Create different classes for each thing you want to animate like

```
class="fade-it1" class="fade-it2" class="fade-it3"
```

and add the same controllers like:

```
controller.addTween('.fade-it', TweenMax.from( $('.fade-it'), .5, {css:{opacity: 0}}));
controller.addTween('.fade-it2', TweenMax.from( $('.fade-it2'), .5, {css:{opacity: 0}}));
controller.addTween('.fade-it3', TweenMax.from( $('.fade-it3'), .5, {css:{opacity: 0}}));
```

I tried it and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Came across this looking for a answer to the same problem.
Seems that the "#fly-it" option also needs to to have some changes to the css file too.
When wanting multiple "#fly-it" in the same html page you will also need to add the following to your css file.

```
#fly-it { position: relative; }
#fly-it2 { position: relative; }
#fly-it3 { position: relative; }
#fly-it4 { position: relative; }
```